# Maxpooling in inception?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks

Maxpooling is performed as one of the steps in inception which yields same output dimension as that of the input.
Can anyone explain how this max pooling is performed?

Answer (score 1):

My bad, didn't look into the block diagram first

[image]

maxpooling filter/kernel is `3x3` = `fxf`

Formula for padding to get the same dimension as the input

`p = (f - 1)/2`

here `f=3` ,so padding to be performed before maxpooling is `(3-1)/2 = 1`